# error upon running tomcat You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd schema

Tags: spring, tomcat

I keep getting an error:

```
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/project-security.xml]; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: 
Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-
security-3.0.xsd or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.2. 
Please update your schema declarations to the 3.2 schema.
```

I have an old deployment server and a new one both CentOS. Basically what I did was install the same Java and copy the tomcat folder including the war files to new the server. But when I run it on the new server it gives me this error.

project-security.xml

```
<beans xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd" 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:cloud="http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring" 
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

project-springapp.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:springapp.xml"/>
    <import resource="project-config.xml"/>
    <import resource="project-services.xml"/>
    <import resource="project-managers.xml"/>
    <import resource="project-security.xml"/>
    <import resource="project-spring.xml"/>
    <import resource="project-partner-beans.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do what error message says and replace references to 3.1 version schemas to 3.2 which seems to be version you are using for spring-security.
But you should check other schema versions too.

project-security.xml

```
<beans xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd" 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:cloud="http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring" 
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

project-springapp.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">
```